# How many VM are started on Android after boot?

Tags: android, virtual-machine

Android dev guide says "Every Android application runs in its own process, with its own instance of the Dalvik virtual machine.". So how many VMs (on 2.3/3.0) are started immediately after boot (if only default apps were initiated)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So how many VMs (on 2.3/3.0) are started immediately after boot

Some number greater than or equal to 1.

The exact number would depend on:

- What software came preinstalled on the device
- What software the user installed
- What version of Android it is
- Possibly other hardware-specific or user-specific characteristics (e.g., selected input method)

You are welcome to use DDMS to examine an emulator and count yourself for some configuration, as most of the listed processes will have Dalvik VMs.

> (if only default apps were initiated)

There is no concept in Android of "default apps".

Comment: I'm new to android, so I'm not quite familiar with an appropriate terminology, but I find it obvious that "default apps", to which I was referring, are intended to be explained as "software preinstalled on the device".

Comment: Btw, "software preinstalled on the device" might include, for example, google maps which is an application. From the definition up here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_(computer_science) it comes that preset (default) software (application) is what, for example, google maps are, and there's a lot of that kind of stuff. => List of those apps can be called "default apps". Otherwise gmaps is not an app and/or is installed by user. That's just if you want to be so pedantic about it.

Comment: @den-javamaniac: You are welcome to whatever opinion you wish to hold. Regardless, there is no immutable canonical roster of "default apps" -- each device has its own set of preinstalled software.

Comment: I'll agree on that, besides it has no actual relation to the matter. Your answer worked well. Thanks.